# How do I inherit attributes from the object Pet1 to my new class owner?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, inheritance

I'm trying to create a class for the pets and another class for the owners that inherit the name and breed etc from the class "Pet". How would I use the pets name from the object Pet1 in the class for the owner?

```
class Pet: #creates a new class pet
   name = ""
   breed =""
   species="" #initialise the class
   age = 0 

   def petInfo(self): # creates a function petInfo to return the values assigned to the object
    Info = ("Your pets name is: %s Your pets breed is: %s Your pets species is: %s and It's age is: %s" % (self.name, self.breed, self.species, self.age))

    return Info

 Pet1 = Pet() #creates a new object Pet1 from the class Pet
 Pet1.petInfo() #accesses the function in the class


 PetsName = input("What is their name? ")
 PetsBreed = input("What is it's breed? ")
 PetsSpecies = input("What is it's species? ") #Ask for input for the new 
 values
 PetsAge = int(input("What is it's age?"))


 Pet1.name = PetsName
 Pet1.breed = PetsBreed
 Pet1.species = PetsSpecies #assigns the inputed values to the object
 Pet1.age = PetsAge

  print(Pet1.petInfo()) #prints the "Info" variable inside the function "petInfo"


 ################################ Inheritance 
  #########################################


 class owner(Pet):
     ownerName = ""
     ownerPostcode = ""
     ownerPhonenumber = ""

     def ownerInfo(self):
         OwnerInformation = ("Owners name is: %s and their pets name is: %s" 
 % (self.ownerName, self.name))

         return OwnerInformation

 Owner1 = owner()
 Owner1.ownerInfo()
 NewName = input("What is your name?: ")
 Owner1.ownerName = NewName

 print(Owner1.ownerInfo())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer composition over inheritance. Owner **is not** a Pet, an owner **has a** pet. I would suggest the following approach:

```
class Owner:

   def __init__(self,pet, address):
       self.pet = pet
       self.address = address 
pet=Pet()
address = Address()
owner = Owner(pet, address)
#owner.pet
```

or pet has an owner:

```
class PetWithOwner(Pet):

   def __init__(self,owner):
       super(PetWithOwner, self).__init__()
       self.pet = pet

owner = Owner()
pet = PetWithOwner(owner)
#pet.owner
```